# Scroll a background image

Tags: jquery, css

I want to scroll a background image until the end pixel and then go backwards to the beginning of the image. I'd like to repeat that sequence continuously.

I have a code, but it scrolls the background image continuously in one direction.

How could I change this code to work as I want?

CSS:

```
body{margin:0; border:0; background:url(ejemplo3.jpg) repeat-x;}
```

HTML:

```
<body></body>
```

JQuery:

```
var scrollSpeed = 50;

// set the default position
var current = 0;

// set the direction
var direction = 'h';

function bgscroll() {
    // 1 pixel row at a time
    current -= 1;

    // move the background with backgrond-position css properties
    $('body').css("backgroundPosition", (direction == 'h') ? current + "px 0" : "0 " + current + "px");
}

//Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
setInterval(bgscroll, scrollSpeed);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have background repeat-x then it will get into a loop hence you will see image rotating in only one direction. But if you keep the image set to no-repeat then your code can be modified as shown below:

**/* Add Background Image (assing your image) */**

```
body{margin:0; border:0; background:url(dsc01549.jpg) no-repeat;}
```

**/* Add Script */**

```
// Global Variables

var scrollSpeed = 50;
// set the default position
var current = 0;
// image height & rotation complete
var _ht,_finishNRot=false;
// set the direction
var direction = 'h';
// create hidden image element to grab height of it for calculation purpose
var url = $('body').css('background-image').replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');
var bgImage = $('<img />');
bgImage.hide().bind('load', function(){ _ht = $(this).height(); });
$('body').append(bgImage);
bgImage.attr('src', url);

function bgscroll() {
// while rotation not completed 
if(_finishNRot==false){ current -= 1;} else {current+=1; } ;
// -ve Rotation completed
if(-(current)==_ht)_finishNRot = true;
// +ve Rotation completed
if((current)==0)_finishNRot = false;
// move the background with backgrond-position css properties
$('body').css("backgroundPosition", (direction == 'h') ? current + "px 0" : "0 " + current + "px");
}

//Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
setInterval(bgscroll, scrollSpeed);
```

Hope this helps you.

Cheers,
Ashok

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with the code, when I have the screen resolutions like 1024 or 1480 the background image does not reach its final pixel (horizontally) or exceeds its final pixel (horizontally), how could I fix that?

Here's an example online: http://www.ideas-web.net63.net/prueba/prueba.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if I understood what you need and the height of the image; try useing 'background-repeat y' and dont fix your background image in your CSS. This should allow you to scroll through the image whilst its in view

Answer (score 0):

you mean something as elegant as this: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/fMHL4/ 
I'd sure love it to read on such a page ;)

```
@keyframes move-body-bg
{
    0% { background-position:left top; }
    50% { background-position:left bottom; }
    100% { background-position:left top; }
}

html,body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/800x2000);
    transition-property: background-position;

    -webkit-animation: move-body-bg 2s infinite; 
    -moz-animation:    move-body-bg 2s infinite; 
    -o-animation:      move-body-bg 2s infinite; 
    animation:         move-body-bg 2s infinite; 
}
```